# AoE II HD black screen problem

Tags: wine, games

I just installed Age Of Empire II HD with Wine (version 1.6.2) on Ubuntu 16.04. Also I don't have Steam. Everything works perfectly except for the map, which stays black!

I know you can solve this problem using the `-nostartup` command but I do not know how it works or where to put it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open a terminal
2. Move to the directory where your game is installed. (If you are using wine, it should be something like `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Age of Empires II HD/`)

   ```
   cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Age of Empires II HD/
   ```
3. Execute:

   ```
   wine "AoK HD.exe" -nostartup
   ```

   Where `AoK HD.exe` is the name of the game binary file. It could also have another name, it depends on the version of the game.
4. Enjoy!

Comment: Wouldn't it be AoE not AoK?

Comment: It could be, it depends on the game version installed